# Why is RSpec printing a string of capital F's out on the top of my terminal screen?

Tags: rspec

I just tried running rspec as I normally did before, which is supposed to give me an output that looks like this:

```
karenlee@Karens-MBP karen_lee % rspec

#caesar_cipher
  encodes a simple word
  wraps around the alphabet
  encodes multiple words

#digital_root
  calculates the digital root of a single-digit number
  calculates the digital root of a larger number
```

But when I ran it today, it gave me an output like this:

```
karenlee@Karens-MBP mancala % rspec
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Failures:

  1) Board#initialize creates a set of 14 cups
     Failure/Error: @cups = Set.new(14)

     ArgumentError:
       value must be enumerable
```

On another note, I also just did a pair programming session over Visual Studio's LiveShare (where I was the host), and I noticed that whenever my partner typed "rspec" into the shared terminal screen on VS Code, the output of the rspec was like the first example in this post. So why is it that when I run "rspec" on my own machine, it prints out the string of "F"s instead of the actual specs like in the first example?

I double checked my gem list and I have the following rspec gems installed (for rspec):

```
rspec (3.9.0, 3.1.0)
rspec-core (3.9.0, 3.1.7)
rspec-expectations (3.9.0, 3.1.2)
rspec-mocks (3.9.0, 3.1.3)
rspec-support (3.9.0, 3.1.2)
rubygems-update (3.0.6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This output format is controlled by `--format` option.

But `rspec` has another feature, where it reads options from `.rspec` file in your project, so you might want to

```
$ cat .rspec
--color
--require rails_helper
```

check `rspec -h` to learn more

```
  **** Output ****

    -f, --format FORMATTER             Choose a formatter.
                                         [p]rogress (default - dots)
                                         [d]ocumentation (group and example names)
                                         [h]tml
                                         [j]son
                                         custom formatter class name
```

The one with `F` for failures, and `.` (dot) for passes is called `progress` format. The other one your partner had is probably `documentation`